# How to show overlay with "showLoading" with fancybox2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In fancybox 1 showLoading would also show an overlay, in Fancybox2 this isn't the default.

Is there a way to show the overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is displayed by default since v2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on [github](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/396):

It is now (since v2.1.2) possible to open and close overlay manually -

```
// Open using default options
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.open();
// Pass custom options
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.open({closeClick : false});
// Close
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.close();
```